# PDF not showing JPEG image

Tags: mozilla, qtwebkit, pdf.js

When I am integrating pdf.js mozilla library with QT webkit I am getting error when pdf has jpeg image it is not showing the image

```
pdf.viewer.js calling readFromStorage function and runhandlers function of pdf.viewer.js javascript and  show warnings/errors  which are listed below :
Warning: Load test font never loaded.
Warning: Error during JPEG image loading
Warning: Dependent image isn't ready yet
Warning: Unhandled rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'localStorage.getItem')
```